# System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: <web service> has not been properly Initialized

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, soapexception

We are having the following setup:

A custom DLL (VB.Net) has a web reference to a custom web service (ASP.Net, let's call it WebService0).

This custom DLL is instantiated by custom .Net EXE program, which make use of the exposed functions in the DLL, which in turn make calls to said WebService0.

e.g. **.Net EXE Program** calls **DLL** function which calls **WebService0**.

This setup works fine.

Now, take this setup **to another computer**, but instead of calling the DLL from a custom program like above, it is being called from yet another web service layer (let's call this one WebService1). And to test this WebService1 there is another .Net EXE program (**not the same one mentioned above**).

e.g. **.Net EXE Program** calls **WebService1**, which calls **custom DLL** function, which in turn calls **WebService0**.

For some reason, this setup throws the following exception:
**System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: *WebService0* has not been properly Initialized**

What could be happening? The cause does not seem to be evident. We have checked everything to the best of our knowledge.

We have searched the internet and there is barely any information about it that we could find.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your WebService1 is the source of this exception, when calling the DLL. And you do NOT have configuration embeded into DLL itself.

You've propably forgot to configure your WebService1 web.config system.serviceModel section.

Take a look at your .Net EXE Program (the first one) and it's App.Config (or YourExeName.exe.config) to see what system.serviceModel section looks like. I expect at least  section to be filled.

Do the same in your WebService1/web.config/system.serviceModel

In case my guess is wrong and you've done this already, show us your configuration.